# Ошибка при поиске ORA-00918

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Всем привет! делаю ADF приложение написал запрос:

```
SELECT q.nlitera,
       q.schange,
       q.scode,
       q.sname,
       q.npagecount,
       q.skeywords,
       q.dcarddate,
       q.niswork,
       q.nisrevoked,
       q.scomment,
       q.ndocumentid,
       w.sname,
       e.scode,
       r.sname,
       t.sname,
       y.sname,
       u.sname,
       u.sname
FROM   ibd_documentcard q, 
       ibd_documenttype w,
       ibd_department e,
       ibd_pageformat r,
       ibd_storingplace t,
       ibd_clgroup y,
       ibd_user u
WHERE  q.ntypeid = w.ntypeid(+)
AND    q.ndepartmentid = e.ndepartmentid(+)
AND    q.npageformatid = r.npageformatid(+)
AND    q.nstoringplaceid = t.nstoringplaceid(+)
AND    q.nclgroupid = y.nclgroupid(+)
AND    q.nuserid = u.nuserid(+)
AND    q.nresponsibleid = u.nuserid(+);
```

На форму данные выводятся и все окей,но когда пытаюсь что-то найти то выводит ошибку:

> ORA 00918 колонка неоднозначно определена

Ткните пальцем где я ошибся(((

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В запросе извлекаются значения колонок с одним и тем же именем `r.sname,t.sname,y.sname,u.sname,u.sname`.

Если ты обернешь этот запрос следущим -

```
select sname
  from (
```

То как Oracle узнает - какое именно поле необходимо извлечь? Поэтому, чтобы избавиться от ORA-00918, для каждого столбца, которое имеет несколько повторов (например sname) необходимо прописать уникальный алиас -

```
...r.sname as r_name, t.sname as t_name, y.sname as y_name,...
```